# Changing data when click button in chart.js/vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, chart.js

- I have this bubble chart, if one data point, **value 2 > 1,000 ; I wish to change its colour to yellow**.
- By **default, each value point is = 1,000** ; If the user clicks on the bubble, I want it to be = 6,000; hence making the bubble go from blue (default) to yellow.

I was able to do the logic, in the console it shows the correct value, but I am trying to figure out how to either:

1. Reload the graph ; passing the new correct values; adjusting the colours appropriately or...
2. Override this graph; making a new graph with adjusted colours

I've looked at the github https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#updating-charts and feel overwhelmed to be honest, I've only coded in Python and only need this small JS element, thanks in advance!

Here's my code I wish to reload the values:

```
<div id="app">
  <graph-bubblecloud
            :width="500"
            :height="500"
            :padding-top="5"
            :padding-bottom="0"
            :padding-left="0"
            :padding-right="0"
            :values="values"
            :colors="colors"
            :styles="styles"
            :render-interval="0"
            @click="onClickEvent">
        <note :text="'Demo Graph v1'" :align="'left'"></note>
    </graph-bubblecloud>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-graph@0.5.3/dist/vue-graph.js"></script>


<script>
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        values: [
            [ "value1", 50, 6000 ],
            [ "value2", 50, 1000 ],
            [ "value3", 50, 1000 ],
            [ "value4", 50, 1000 ],
            [ "value5", 50, 1000 ],
            [ "value6", 50, 1000 ],
            [ "value6", 50, 1000 ]
        ],
        colors: function(data) {
            if (data[2] <= 1000) {
              return '#497eff';
            } else {
              return '#ffff00';
            }
        },
        styles: {
            titleFontSize: 19,
            titleFontWeight: 'bold'
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onClickEvent: function(obj, e) {
            console.log(obj.data);
            if (obj.data[2] > 1000) {
              obj.data[2] = 6000;

            } else {
              obj.data[2] = 6000;
            }
        }

    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this to update chart with new data:

```
    this.renderChart(this.chartdata, this.options)
```